# while loop cannot run

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

how do i loop back this data. this is part of a bigger code. after this statement ends i will also need to input another str to loop back into a bigger while loop.

```
specificReport = "yes"

while specificReport == "yes":
    specificReport = str.lower(input("Do you want to look at the specific report (yes/no) : " ))
    option2 = input("Which data are you looking for (1. Location Name, 2.Risk Type, 3. Risk Level , 4. Date & Time): ")
    if int(option2) == 1:
        locationValue = input("Enter the location you want to inspect: ")   
        print(df.loc[df['Location Name'] == locationValue])
    elif int(option2) == 2:
        riskTypeValue = str.lower(input("Enter the risk type you want to inspect: "))
        print(df.loc[df['Risk Type'] == riskTypeValue])
    elif int(option2) == 3:
        riskLevelValue = str.lower(input("Enter the location you want to inspect: "))   
        print(df.loc[df['Risk Level'] == riskLevelValue])                    
    elif int(option2) == 4:
        dAndtValue = input("Enter the location you want to inspect: ")   
        print(df.loc[df['Date & Time'] == dAndtValue])                    
    else:
        print("You have keyed in an invalid option")
```

Comment: because the loop will run until the condition is true. Currently, it is always true and never updated.  I guess, setting the initial value to something else than "yes" may help

Comment: Have you considered writing a function to handle this task? If there's another while loop, don't touch it or its variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the `specificReport`. For example like this:

```py
specificReport = "yes"

while specificReport == "yes":
    specificReport = str.lower(input("Do you want to look at the specific report (yes/no) : " ))
    option2 = input("Which data are you looking for (1. Location Name, 2.Risk Type, 3. Risk Level , 4. Date & Time): ")
    if int(option2) == 1:
        locationValue = input("Enter the location you want to inspect: ")   
        print(df.loc[df['Location Name'] == locationValue])
    elif int(option2) == 2:
        riskTypeValue = str.lower(input("Enter the risk type you want to inspect: "))
        print(df.loc[df['Risk Type'] == riskTypeValue])
    elif int(option2) == 3:
        riskLevelValue = str.lower(input("Enter the location you want to inspect: "))   
        print(df.loc[df['Risk Level'] == riskLevelValue])                    
    elif int(option2) == 4:
        dAndtValue = input("Enter the location you want to inspect: ")   
        print(df.loc[df['Date & Time'] == dAndtValue])                    
    else:
        print("You have keyed in an invalid option")
        specificReport = "no"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop one more time, you will have to set `specificReport == "yes"` at the end of your while loop.

Because you are changing it here (at the first line of the loop):

```
specificReport = str.lower(input("Do you want to look at the specific report (yes/no) : " ))
```

And not returning it to `"yes"` at the end.

May I suggest using `while True:` instead and `if condition: break` when you reach a condition that you want it to stop looping, this way you dont have to use string comparison `specificReport == "yes"` to define your loop progression.

```
while True:
    specificReport = str.lower(input("Do you want to look at the specific report (yes/no) : " ))
    option2 = input("Which data are you looking for (1. Location Name, 2.Risk Type, 3. Risk Level , 4. Date & Time, 5. Exit): ")
    if int(option2) == 1:
        locationValue = input("Enter the location you want to inspect: ")   
        print(df.loc[df['Location Name'] == locationValue])
    elif int(option2) == 2:
        riskTypeValue = str.lower(input("Enter the risk type you want to inspect: "))
        print(df.loc[df['Risk Type'] == riskTypeValue])
    elif int(option2) == 3:
        riskLevelValue = str.lower(input("Enter the location you want to inspect: "))   
        print(df.loc[df['Risk Level'] == riskLevelValue])                    
    elif int(option2) == 4:
        dAndtValue = input("Enter the location you want to inspect: ")   
        print(df.loc[df['Date & Time'] == dAndtValue])
    elif int(option2) == 5:
        print("Exiting")
        break
    else:
        print("You have keyed in an invalid option")
```